# Can an HTML5 Video fire a jQuery function ontimeupdate?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am able to fire a javaScript function when ontimeupdate runs from the HTML5 video tag (I believe this runs every 250ms while the video is playing). Here is the snippet:

```
<video src="men-2.mp4"  ontimeupdate="createThumbs()" width="640" height="480" controls="controls" id="myVideo">

function createThumbs(){
    //Stuff is happening here...
}
```

The problem I have is I can't figure out how to fire a jQuery script on this event. There is no ontimeupdate event for jQuery as far as I know. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myVideo").bind('timeupdate', createThumbs);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Did not know that the timeupdate event type would work.

Comment: Updated code would be `$('#myVideo').on('timeupdate', createThumbs);`